# Can I connect to a Tarpc RPC Service without using anything but the address from the server?

Tags: rust, rpc

I am using [Tarpc](https://github.com/google/tarpc).

**Client**

```
let (_, mut auth_reactor) = auth::spawn_server(auth_server_address);
let auth_client: auth::FutureClient = auth_reactor
    .run(auth::FutureClient::connect(
        auth_server_address,
        client::Options::default(),
    ))
    .unwrap();

auth_reactor
    .run(
        auth_client
            .authme(byte_vector_auth.clone())
            .map_err(|e| println!("{}", e))
            .and_then(|i| {
                println!("{:?}", i);
                Ok(())
            }),
    )
    .unwrap();
```

**Server**

```
pub fn spawn_server(address: SocketAddr) -> (server::Handle, reactor::Core) {
    let reactor = reactor::Core::new().unwrap();
    client::Options::default().handle(reactor.handle());
    let (auth_handler, server) = AuthServer
        .listen(address, &reactor.handle(), server::Options::default())
        .unwrap();
    reactor.handle().spawn(server);
    return (auth_handler, reactor);
}
```

I'm returning the reactor because I need it for the client.

Answer (score 1):

Using tokio, you need a reactor to run your async client.
I don't think you need to use the same reactor as the server, but you can have only one reactor per thread.

So you can spawn a client thread, or even build a different binary for your client.

You will have to get server address in another way, but that shouldn't be too hard ;)